# How to keep date info?

Tags: java, date

In java, I want to know that what is the best practice to keep date info for display, query, report etc. It seems that if we persist as long, all timezone dependency will be removed and we will keep 'persist globally, display locally' principle since Date object automatically converts long to current timezone.

But what is the advantage of persisting as Date object?
Do I loose any info other than info owner's timezone?
Can I get any wrong info when DLS takes into account?
Difference between persisting as UTC date and long is just readable db info?

Comment: It's not clear what language/framework you are using. Is it .Net, Java, Javascript?

Comment: My question is not language dependent. But still, I edited as java

Comment: Might be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303676/is-it-java-best-practice-to-store-dates-as-longs-in-your-database

Comment: Its not really clear what exactly you are after. If you want to persist Date information then you should use Timestamp with time zone.

Comment: Have you looked at Joda `DateTime`? Much improved over `Date`.

Comment: Yeah @vikingsteve. It has really good points. But Im going after the best practice to persist date info into db for display, query, report etc.

Comment: Merhaba Mustafa, in my experience a db-specific datetime data-type in UTC is best. Then convert it to local timezone when you display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your database you should use either `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` or you convert it to `UTC` time and store it as `long`.

The first one relies on the DB to handle it correctly (the DB will, but will your DB driver? You have to test this for your setup). The second one makes it a manual process, you will get the correct result in the end but will have more hazzle with it because you have to take care about everything.

Inside Java you might want to use `Calendar` over `Date` because there you can specify the `TIMEZONE` etc. manually, thus you are able to display Dates in timezones different to your own easier.

Comment: isn't long value already in UTC? do i need to convert it into utc before converting to long?

Comment: Usually long value is timezone agnostic: if you get it from local time it contains number of milliseconds from local 1/1/1970, if you get it from UTC time it starts from UTC 1/1/1970.

Comment: @MustafaGenç Yes, No. It depends on how you insert it into the `Date`. The `Date` class only uses the `local` (e.G. ON YOUR SERVER) Timezone. But that also means that it will use Daylight Saving Time Offsets. (e.G. there is no 02.30 at the last Monday in October in Germany as the time skips from 02.00 to 03.00) So, if you want to use `Date` be sure to set your local timezone to UTC.